# Can MPI_Gather be used to receive data from threads that use MPI_Send?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a master process and more slave processes. I want that every slave process to send back to the master one integer, so I guess I should gather them using MPI_Gather. But somehow it doesn't work and I started to think that MPI_Gather is incompatible with MPI_Send.

The relevant lines of code look like this:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_count);

int full_word_count = 0;
int* receiving_buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);

if (process_id == 0)
{
    // Some Master code here ...

    MPI_Gather(full_word_count, 1, MPI_INT, receiving_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // ...
}
else
{
    // Some Slave code here ...

    MPI_Send(full_word_count, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //...
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

I also know that I used "1" for MPI_Gather because I tried to run only for two processes, so process 1 would send, and process 0 would gather; of course, for more processes I should modify it using ranks. But my main question here is that I can use (and if yes, how) MPI_Gather combined with MPI_Send for a situation like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Gather()` is a collective operation and must hence be called by all the ranks of the communicator. They also must provide matching signatures (datatype and count) and all use the same `root` value.

Note the send buffer of the `root` rank is also gathered into the receive buffers, so if the send count is `1`, you really should allocate your receive buffer with

```
int* receiving_buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * process_count)
```

and since all ranks send `1 * MPI_INT`, a correct receive signature is also be `1 * MPI_INT`.

Also note that "threads" is improper in this context. MPI tasks or MPI processes are the right terminology.

Keep in mind that the standard does not specify how a collective operation should be implemented. In the case of `MPI_Gather()`, a naive implementation would have all MPI tasks send their buffer to the root rank. But some more sophisticated algorithm can be used such as a tree-based gather, and in that case, not all tasks would send their buffer to the root rank.